# how to append to a list after its last element in loop in R?

Tags: r, list, vector, append, addition

I have vector name: `block_sizes=c(3,3,4)` and I want to make a list which it has `block_sizes[1]` number of 1s,`block_sizes[2]` number of 2s ,and `block_sizes[3]` of 3s, etc.

In this example, I should give `[3,3,4]` to my code and get `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]`.

I wrote the code below, but I don't know why it gives me `[0,3,3,3,3]`. I think it is because I should have appended to last element of vector which I am not now. Any input is appreciated.

````
vector=0
for (i in length(block_sizes )) {
  buf=rep.int(i,times =block_sizes[i])
  membership_vector=append(vector,buf)

  }```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rep` without any loop as the `times` parameter is vectorized

```
rep(seq_along(block_sizes), block_sizes)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Or for the faster implementation

```
rep.int(seq_along(block_sizes), times = block_sizes)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

---

Or if we need a loop

```
v1 <- c()
for(i in seq_along(block_sizes)) {
   v1 <- c(v1, rep.int(i, times = block_sizes[i]))
 }
```

#### data

```
block_sizes <- c(3, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mapply`:

```
unlist(mapply(rep, c(1,2,3), c(3,3,4))

# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Comment: i dont have c(1,2,3) .its different each times.its just an example.thanks

Comment: @ssssoooo doesn't matter, you can use it like this: ```unlist(mapply(rep, seq_along(block_sizes), block_sizes)``` or  ```unlist(mapply(rep, vector_of_items_to_be_repated, block_sizes)```

Comment: yes this is true i didnt know we have this seq_along()  function.thanks